# Trying to create a CSV file for an automation around dokan_profile_settings but having trouble with quoting getting messed

Tags: python, wordpress, csv, woocommerce, dokan

I have a script that reads in the contents of a CSV file where I then merge it with other data with the goal of creating an output CSV file that has the combined data.  I have the CSV file creating working fine and all of the data makes it into the output file.  My issue is with formatting specific to a cell of data that contains many fields that are already quoted.  I have messed around with the CSV options and cannot find a configuration that doesn't make me use single quotes around everything (which the import into Dokan will accept but not process properly) or that doesn't double double quote everything which also breaks the import mechanism with Dokan.

Here is what the data element looks like (not pretty):  Note that there are many | delimited fields prior to this and after - this is just a single field called "dokan_profile_setting"

```py
'a:19:{s:10:"store_name";s:12:"vendor100";s:6:"social";a:8:{s:2:"fb";s:0:"";s:5:"gplus";s:0:"";s:7:"twitter";s:0:"";s:9:"pinterest";s:0:"";s:8:"linkedin";s:0:"";s:7:"youtube";s:0:"";s:9:"instagram";s:0:"";s:6:"flickr";s:0:"";}s:7:"payment";a:2:{s:6:"paypal";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"email";}s:4:"bank";a:0:{}}s:5:"phone";s:10:"1231231234";s:10:"show_email";s:2:"no";s:7:"address";a:6:{s:8:"street_1";s:21:"2160 South Lipan Street";s:8:"street_2";s:9:"";s:4:"city";s:6:"Denver";s:3:"zip";s:5:"80223";s:7:"country";s:2:"US";s:5:"state";s:2:"CO";}s:8:"location";s:0:"";s:6:"banner";i:0;s:4:"icon";i:0;s:8:"gravatar";i:0;s:14:"show_more_ptab";s:3:"yes";s:9:"store_ppp";i:10;s:10:"enable_tnc";s:3:"off";s:9:"store_tnc";s:0:"";s:23:"show_min_order_discount";s:2:"no";s:9:"store_seo";a:0:{}s:24:"dokan_store_time_enabled";s:3:"yes";s:23:"dokan_store_open_notice";s:0:"";s:24:"dokan_store_close_notice";s:0:"";}'
```

If the quotes are clean - as above - and not doubled (see below) the import and usage works fine but i cannot seem to get the CSV creation to leave these quotes along while affecting others in the row that legit need to be quoted.

Here is a single row after output by CSV filewriter - Note the doubled quotes

```py
"100"|"vendor100"|"vendor100@demotech.com"|"Piper"|"Smith"|"vendor100"|"vendor100"|"This is the imported shop data for XYZ LLC"|""|"no"|"a:19:{s:10:""store_name"";s:12:""vendor100"";s:6:""social"";a:8:{s:2:""fb"";s:0:"""";s:5:""gplus"";s:0:"""";s:7:""twitter"";s:0:"""";s:9:""pinterest"";s:0:"""";s:8:""linkedin"";s:0:"""";s:7:""youtube"";s:0:"""";s:9:""instagram"";s:0:"""";s:6:""flickr"";s:0:"""";}s:7:""payment"";a:2:{s:6:""paypal"";a:1:{i:0;s:5:""email"";}s:4:""bank"";a:0:{}}s:5:""phone"";s:10:""1231231234"";s:10:""show_email"";s:2:""no"";s:7:""address"";a:6:{s:8:""street_1"";s:21:""2160 South Lipan Street"";s:8:""street_2"";s:9:"""";s:4:""city"";s:6:""Denver"";s:3:""zip"";s:5:""80223"";s:7:""country"";s:2:""US"";s:5:""state"";s:2:""CO"";}s:8:""location"";s:0:"""";s:6:""banner"";i:0;s:4:""icon"";i:0;s:8:""gravatar"";i:0;s:14:""show_more_ptab"";s:3:""yes"";s:9:""store_ppp"";i:10;s:10:""enable_tnc"";s:3:""off"";s:9:""store_tnc"";s:0:"""";s:23:""show_min_order_discount"";s:2:""no"";s:9:""store_seo"";a:0:{}s:24:""dokan_store_time_enabled"";s:3:""yes"";s:23:""dokan_store_open_notice"";s:0:"""";s:24:""dokan_store_close_notice"";s:0:"""";}"|"vendor100"|"no"|"Piper"|"Smith"|"XYZ LLC 100"|"2160 South Lipan Street"|""|"Denver"|"CO"|"80223"|"US"|"vendor100@demotech.com"|"(123) 123-1234"|""|"percentage"|"yes"|"39.6773216"|"-105.0014567"|"1"|"2160 South Lipan Street, Denver, CO, 80223, USA"|""|""|""|"yes"|"yes"|"CO"|"404-00411"|"vendor100"|"1231231234"|"a:6:{s:8:""street_1"";s:15:""2160 South Lipan Street"";s:8:""street_2"";s:0:"""";s:4:""city"";s:6:""Denver"";s:5:""state"";s:2:""CO"";s:3:""zip"";s:5:""80223"";s:14:""country_select"";s:2:""US"";}"|""|"seller"|"$P$B8l8bYi8oIwINynO/x3Lb/80vOUfGD."|"0"
```

Here is the current config of my csv writer but i have been through many diff configs.  This is just the current one that generated the output above:

```py
with open(demo_co_vendors, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar='"', doublequote="false", escapechar='\\')
```

Any advice or help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`, it should stop "quoting" the values
*Hope this helps...*

Comment: I removed the section as noted and have the same behavior.  The characters there were not part of the field in question nor previously quoted did not get quoted this time around (as expected) but the main field that is my issue is still getting doubled.  Here is snip:

"a:19:{s:10:""store_name"";s:12:""vendor100"";s:6:""social"";a:8:{s:2:""fb"";s:0:"""";s:5:""gplus"";s:0:"""";s:7:""twitter"";s:0:"""";s:9:""pinterest"";s:0:"""";s:8:""linkedin"";s:0:"""";s:7:""youtube"";s:0:"""";s:9:""instagram"";s:0:"""";s:6:""flickr"";s: